# Does Kale have 2 or 3 transformations already?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

The Dragon Ball Wikia (which isnt an official Dragon Ball Source) claims Kale have 3 transformations,

1 [Berserker Super Saiyan](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Berserker_Super_Saiyan)

2 [Super Saiyan Perfect Energy Control](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Super_Saiyan_(perfect_energy_control)) (this name isnt even mentioned in the series)

3 [True Legendary Super Saiyan](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/True_Legendary_Super_Saiyan)

Now the supposed transformations 2 and 3 look very similar, personally I cant really tell if they are different transformations. The Dragon Ball Wikia claims they are slightly different in color at least (green vs yellowish brownish green) This difference could even be simply a different animator. My question therefore is, does Kale have 2 or 3 transformations already? Can you tell differences between the supposed transformations 2 and 3?

Answer (score 1):

Kale has 2 transformations.

The first would be Super Saiyan Green: This is a variation of the regular SSJ transformation where there is a tinge of Green in Kale's hair. In terms of power, it pretty much is identical to the SSJ transformation because in the earlier stage of the battle, SSJ2 Caulfifla did appear to be stronger and Kale was also intimidated by the SSJ3 transformation.

The second transformation would be The Legendary Super Saiyan transformation: The reason I'm not mentioning the Berserker state is because, it is an uncontrolled version of the fully mastered Legendary Super Saiayan. The Bereseker state only resulted in a tremendous power increase but Kale was not able to control it and once she did it evolved into this transformation. This transformation is significantly stronger than an SSJ2 regular transformation. This is because we see her going toe to toe with SSJG Goku and SSJ2 Caulifla on ther hand was completely outclassed by SSJG Goku.

Note: The names aren't officially confirmed apart from Super Saiyan Berserker which seemed to be an uncontrolled state of LSSJ. Since Broly isn't Cannon, we can not conclude with certainty. However, the 2 kinds of transformations and the information mentioned above with regard to the power and kind of transformation and the number of transformations Kale has is indeed accurate.